# PnP Provisioning | Create a SharePoint list with rating enabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-provision

We are unable to create a SharePoint list with rating enabled on it.
Can someone help us in creating XML schema for the above requirement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a test list and enable ratings. Extract a template containing the list and you will see relevant artifacts. You will need to sure the underlying columns such as `ratedby` under the site fields element

Answer (score 0):

For rating enabled list, we need to add 6 column below, 4 for rating and 2 for likes:

```
Guid RatingsFieldGuid_AverageRating = new Guid("5a14d1ab-1513-48c7-97b3-657a5ba6c742");
             Guid RatingsFieldGuid_RatingCount = new Guid("b1996002-9167-45e5-a4df-b2c41c6723c7");
             Guid RatingsFieldGuid_RatedBy = new Guid("4D64B067-08C3-43DC-A87B-8B8E01673313");
             Guid RatingsFieldGuid_Ratings = new Guid("434F51FB-FFD2-4A0E-A03B-CA3131AC67BA");
             Guid LikeFieldGuid_LikedBy = new Guid("2cdcd5eb-846d-4f4d-9aaf-73e8e73c7312");
             Guid LikeFieldGuid_LikeCount = new Guid("6e4d832b-f610-41a8-b3e0-239608efda41");
```

Then you could enable the rating settings using PnP C# code like below:

[How To Enable Ratings/Likes For A List In SharePoint Office 365 Programmatically Using PNP C#](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Enable-RatingsLikes-For-a-List-in-SharePoint-Office-365-Programmatically-using-PNP-C)

For list schema definition, you could simply create a list with rating enabled and then get the list schema using PnP PowerShell:

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/jerrydev/ –Credentials (Get-Credential)
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity "ratinglist" -Includes SchemaXml
$list.SchemaXml
```

It will return the whole schema definition then you could use to provision.